# Scrape data from a website and post it on the blog

Tags: import, automation

This could be in DocType, but I'm looking for a way to scrape data and post it automatically.

I wanted to fetch those data from a website and automatically post it on my blog. It doesn't have rss or an API to get those data, so I need to manually copy and paste it one-by-one and post it on WordPress.

Do you know an alternative option for my process?

Comment: There are [services that monitor changes to a page and put them in a feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93439/add-rss-to-any-website/93510#93510), is this what you need?

Comment: can you name some services and i'll go check it out. basically I wanna get those data daily that are being added in the pages of the website. each page contains fresh data to be added on the blog. so i need to monitor if it has a new page.

Answer (score 1):

While importing from machine-readable formats, such as RSS is quite straightforward and usually has plenty of tools around... it is very different story with arbitrary HTML.

If you are not up to code this from scratch, then closest semi-automated tool I know is [Dapper](http://open.dapper.net/) - it can process HTML pages and according to rules that you setup in visual interface convert it to other formats, including XML and RSS. On other hand I am not sure it will be able to handle your requirement of page discovery.